# How can I run different projects from a script in windows?

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio, scripting

I have two visual studio projects (for different purpose... they act on two different hardware) and also, I have a Java project that have control on something else. I am working in windows. My question is that how can I write a script (like shell script) to control different projects from a single program. More specifically, suppose I want to do something like this: execute project 1 with parameters x1,x2,...,xn, then execute project 2 with parameters y1,y2,...,yn, then execute project 1, then project 3, & so on...

Is there any tutorial or short description that I can follow to implement my concept?

Comment: You mean you want to run an executable with different arguments? Like `my.exe a b c` and then `my.exe d e f` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get this right. Do you only want to have a script that acts kinda like a run order (including different arguments)?

Comment: Yes I want something like that. Will this work for the Java project too? Sometimes I want to put some amount of sleep time too between two commands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a myriad of options/scripting languages/... to achieve this, but if you just want to run a bunch of exes then a simple windows batch file will do just fine:

```
@echo off
set my_exe=c:\path\to\my.exe
set my_other_exe=c:\path\to\my_other.exe
%my_exe% a
%my_exe% a b c
%my_other_exe% x
%my_other_exe% x y z
pause
```

Save this with your favourite editor with a `.bat` extension and run by double-clicking. The lines with `set` create variables so you don't have to paste the full path to your exes the whole time. The lines referring to those variables will invoke the executables aith the argumenst that come after it. Search the internet for 'batch file examples' or something like that and you will quickly find all the info needed.